# How to Shuffle / Randomize images in macOS Photos Slideshow?

Tags: macos, mac, photos, slideshow

I'm creating a slideshow project on my Mac via Photos.app

I've added 300+ images to the slideshow. I want them to appear in a random order. Randomization of a slideshow should be an extremely commonly desired feature.

However, Photos.app does not appear to have any option to randomize or shuffle the photos. I'm able to manually re-order the timeline of photos at the bottom, but that's too much work for a large slideshow.

How can I display a randomized slideshow in macOS Photos?

[image]

Comment: Did you find an answer? Looking to do the same thing.

Comment: @TylerNZ. Nope. Press "follow". Upvotes or a bounty welcome...

Answer (score 3):

Strangely enough, this feature doesn't exist in macOS Photos. A couple of workarounds:

1. Create an album containing the slideshow photos > Go to System Preferences > Desktop and Screensaver > Albums > select the album you created > Specify the transition time > "Random order" box will become enabled > Check mark it.
2. Try this AppleScript: http://oldtoad.net/ASC/RandomSortSlideshow.zip

Of course, you could export the photos and use one of the many slideshow generator programs to shuffle, add music etc.